# How to get the average of only positive numbers in a numpy array?

Tags: python

We were given two text files that contain numbers and we need to load them using `numpy.loadtxt` and then find the mean of only the positive numbers within the text files.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
A = np.loadtxt('A.txt')
B = np.loadtxt('B.txt')
A_mean = np.mean(np.where(A>0))
B_mean = np.mean(np.where(B>0))
print(f'A={A_mean}')
print(f'B={B_mean}')
```

I know this is obviously wrong since it appears to be returning the average of the index numbers, not the values. How can I get the average of the actual values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.where(A > 0)` returns the indices where `A > 0` as you noticed. To get the elements of `A`, use the indices: `np.mean(A[np.where(A > 0)])`.

But wait, `A > 0` is a boolean array that has `True` in every element that meets the condition and `False` elsewhere. Such an array is called a "mask", and can be used for indexing as well:

```
A[A > 0].mean()
```

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't even think about putting the brackets around it...thank you! Slowly getting the hang of the language.

Comment: @D.Mellen. Indices and masks are pretty useless unless you index or mask something with them :)